# How can I get my current date ios Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

Specifically I would like to `print` my current date formatted like this -  `2016-12-08 03:37:22 +0000`.  I've tried NSDateComponents.  Swift 2.1 is telling me `NSSecondCalendarUnit` is deprecated and it doesn't recognize `NSCalendarUnitSecond`.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You may want to read this article: http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

Comment: @AhiyaHiya please see my further research.  Swift is not letting me get the day component from NSCalendar

Comment: You do not want to use `NSDateComponents` at all for this.

Answer (score 12):

I put this code together just by reading the iOS Swift DateFormatter documentation available in Xcode:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
//2016-12-08 03:37:22 +0000
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let now = Date()
let dateString = formatter.string(from:now)
NSLog("%@", dateString)
```

Comment: Close - you want `Z`, not `ZZZZZ` for the timezone. `Z` gives `+0000`, `ZZZZZ` gives `+00:00`.